# radio button status verification

Tags: python-3.x

I have 3 radio buttons like so

```
Dialog = Tk()

Radio1 = Radiobutton(Dialog, text="Radio 1", value=1)
Radio1.pack()
Radio2 = Radiobutton(Dialog, text="Radio 2", value=2)
Radio2.pack()
Radio3 = Radiobutton(Dialog, text="Radio 3", value=3)
Radio3.pack()

Dialog.mainloop()
```

I want to do 3 different things depending on which button is selected. I just can't find how to go about doing it. How can I check if the radio button is selected?

```
if Radio1??? == on???:
    do this
elif Radio2??? == on??:
    do that
else:
    do this and that
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a variable to store the selected item

```
v = IntVar()

Radio1 = Radiobutton(Dialog, text="Radio 1", value=1, variable=v)
...
Radio2 = Radiobutton(Dialog, text="Radio 2", value=2, variable=v)
...
...
```

Now you can use

```
if v.get() == 1:
   # do first thing
elif v.get() == 2:
   # etc
else:
   # etc
```